How to add a transparent margin to a png file in Gimp
I have a png file in GIMP and I want to add a transparent margin 25% of the width around the figure. How can I do that?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "around the figure"?  What kind of figure?  Do you want to add a margin by increasing the size of the original, or do you want to delete part of the image to make it transparent?

@BillyKerr: Thanks Billy for the comment. Actually the figure should just be in the middle of the image and around the figure there should be a transparent margin of 25% of the widht. So the original figure (which is a house) has the shape of a rectangle and should be centered and around the rectangle there should be the margin.

I'll ask again. Do you want to increase the image size by adding an additional transparent margin or create a transparent margin by deleting part of the image?  Can't answer this properly without knowing which.  If you can't explain this, share an image showing what you want to do.

Image > Canvas size. And since you want a 25% margin, you want the canvas to be 50% bigger, so you can make Gimp compute it for you:

Another solution with Gimp 2.10 is to use the Crop tool with the Allow growing option set and the Delete cropped pixels unset. This gives more freedom on the canvas position, but there are fewer options to resize/fill layers.


Thanks a lot xenoid for your answer. How can I shift the image a little bit more to the left (or right) with you approach. Unfortunately, the Offset always sets back the changes values to 0

@VanessaF "the Offset always sets back the changes values to 0" : what values? As far as I can tell the Offset does what it should do... (unless you think it is an adjustment to the position you have set in the image widget, but it's not).

Thanks for your comment. If I just open the canvas size of the image and then play around with the offset, it does not change anything as it always changes the values to 0. So how can I shift the figure a little bit more to the left? In my case this is not possible with the offset option so I need to find another way

So you want to increase the canvas size but still have the left part of the image outside of the canvas?

I just want to shift the main figure a little bit to the left after or while increasing the canvas size

To the left of what? See if the other solution I just added (Crop tool) works better for you.

Thanks for your answer and effort xenoid. What I actually want it to shift the basic figure a little bit to the left such that it is not exactly in the center but a little bit more on the left side. Unfortunately, the offset option is not working in the canvas size for a picture whose size has not changed (and only slightly works when the picture has slightly changed).

Suddenly this doesn't really fit the original question? This would just be the Move tool?

I think that it should also be possible normally with the offset option but this is unfortunately not working as it sets all values to 0 and thus I can't move the image. Maybe the move tool is the better option. How does that work?

You activate the tool and click and drag the layer. If you want a specific offset, you can use the cursor keys while watching the displacement indicated at the bottom of the screen.

Thanks xenoid for your great help. I really appreciate it.
